# Filter all types of whitespace in PHP

Tags: php, whitespace

I know that there are many types of space (em space, en space, thin space, non-breaking space, etc), but, all these, that I refered, have HTML entities (at least, PHP's htmlentities() return something like &emsp;.

But, what about those spaces that have no HTML entities?
Example: [example URL not valid anymore]
Look at the nickname of this account. It has many " " (spaces) at the front, which are visible for us (this doesn't happen with the &nbsp;).

I tried already filter with regular expressions, using \x escape, filter with str_replace(), with the space as the argument, and no luck at all!

Do you have any suggestion on how to filter ALL  types of whitespace?

Comment: Short answer: `$new_string = preg_replace('/\s/u', '', $old_string);`

Comment: Thank you. See Accepted Answer below. `\s` doesn't match all whitespace.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\s` by default, will *not* match whitespace characters with values greater than 128. To get at those, you can instead make good use of other UTF-8-aware sequences.

---

<sup>(Standard disclaimer: I'm skimming the PCRE source code to compile the lists below, I may miss a character or type something incorrectly. Please forgive me.)</sup>

`\p{Zs}` matches:

- U+0020 Space
- U+00A0 No-break space
- U+1680 Ogham space mark
- U+180E Mongolian vowel separator
- U+2000 En quad
- U+2001 Em quad
- U+2002 En space
- U+2003 Em space
- U+2004 Three-per-em space
- U+2005 Four-per-em space
- U+2006 Six-per-em space
- U+2007 Figure space
- U+2008 Punctuation space
- U+2009 Thin space
- U+200A Hair space
- U+202F Narrow no-break space
- U+205F Medium mathematical space
- U+3000 Ideographic space

`\h` (Horizontal whitespace) matches the same as `\p{Zs}` above, plus

- U+0009 Horizontal tab.

Similarly for matching vertical whitespace there are a few options.

`\p{Zl}` matches U+2028 Line separator.

`\p{Zp}` matches U+2029 Paragraph separator.

`\v` (Vertical whitespace) matches `\p{Zl}`, `\p{Zp}` and the following

- U+000A Linefeed
- U+000B Vertical tab
- U+000C Formfeed
- U+000D Carriage return
- U+0085 Next line

Going back to the beginning, in UTF-8 mode (i.e. using the `u` pattern modifier) `\s` will match any character that `\p{Z}` matches (which is anything that `\p{Zs}`, `\p{Zl}` and `\p{Zp}` will match), plus

- U+0009 Horizontal tab
- U+000A Linefeed
- U+000C Formfeed
- U+000D Carriage return

---

To cut a long story short (I bet you read all of the above, didn't you?) you might want to use `\s` but make sure to be in UTF-8 mode like `/\s/u`. Putting that to some practical use, to filter out those matching whitespace characters from a string you would do something like

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/\s/u', '', $old_string);
```

Finally, if you really, really care about the vertical whitespaces which aren't included in `\s` (LF and NEL) then you can use the character class `[\s\v]` to match all 26 of the whitespace characters listed above.

Comment: I don't know why, but none of them finds `\u2005` in my PHP code. Any ideas?

Comment: @user5950 several ideas, but the comments section here isn't the place for it. [`\p{Zs}` does match `\u2005`](https://eval.in/private/49194419571098). Perhaps as a new question, detailing your troubles?

Answer (score 2):

They are all plain spaces (returning character code 32) that can be caught with regular expressions or [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim).

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $text);
```

Comment: I use (mb_)trim() by default for all user input, and I tried \s already, and both do not work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $yourString)
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php for more infos on the `\s`