# Delete EN space from string on PHP

Tags: php, regex, ascii, trim

In one pice of my code detect that `rtrim()` not delete a space at end of strings.

Investigating, I see that string contain a **EN SPACE** (U+2002)

```
$str = 'ANDREWS CAROLE [US]';
// rawurlencode($s) //--> "ANDREWS%20CAROLE%E2%80%82%5BUS%5D"
$pat = "/\[(.*?)\]/";
$str = preg_replace($pat,'',$str); //--> "ANDREWS CAROLE " -> ANDREWS%20CAROLE%E2%80%82"
```

Try but fail [Filter all types of whitespace in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230623/filter-all-types-of-whitespace-in-php)

```
$new = preg_replace('\p{Zs}$', '', $s)
```

I don't know `$character_mask` value for this space for use with `rtrim`

Comment: And if you use regex delimiters and add `u` modifier? Use `preg_replace('~\s+$~u', '', $s)`

Comment: Try a 1-regex approach - http://ideone.com/NfIvdZ. Well, if there is an EN-space at the start of the string, it will remain. So, perhaps, using your two step approach might turn out safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[\p{Z}\t]*` before your pattern to match zero or more optional  whitespaces including unicode whitespaces:

```
$str = 'ANDREWS CAROLE [US]';
var_dump ( preg_replace('/[\p{Z}\t]*\[(.*?)\]/u', '', $str) );
//=> string(14) "ANDREWS CAROLE"
```

Comment: Last question.. sometimes `$str = 'ANDREWS CAROLE '` and last is a EN SPACE.

Comment: You can use this then: `preg_replace('/[\p{Z}\t]*(\[(.*?)\])?$/u', '', $str)`

Answer (score 0):

di you try:

```
<?php

$string = preg_replace('/\s*\[(.*?)\]/u','', 'ANDREWS CAROLE [US]');

var_dump($string);
```

output:

```
string(14) "ANDREWS CAROLE"
```

Comment: Yes, my suggestion, should work. Change to `'/\s*(?:\[(.*?)\])?/u'` to support the trailing whitespace removal.